# Android app programming- not sure why findViewByID does the following:

Tags: android, android-fragments

This code works:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        String weather = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if(weather != null) {
            TextView textViewWeather=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.weatherText);
            textViewWeather.setText(weather);
```

BUT if you replace, in the line

`(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.weatherText);`

`rootView` by `findView()` or `getActivity`, it returns null so the next line creates a run time fatal error which halts the program.

I don't understand why. I thought that the context is the activity?! I'm confused,and can't find a good answer via android developer,so here I am...

Thanks in advance to whoever helps!!

Comment: Can you post xml please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line gets the element with id `weatherText` from its `rootView`. Which is nothing but your fragment xml file

```
TextView textViewWeather=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.weatherText);
```

Now if you are replacing above code with below

```
TextView textViewWeather=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.weatherText);
```

**now the parent Activity in which this fragment is hosted which has `TextView` and id `weatherText` will be searched by framework**.
 Which is obvious is not present at all.

Answer (score 1):

when you call :

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
TextView textViewWeather=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.weatherText);
```

the *rootView* now contains the views that are defined in *fargment_detail.xml* .
and *weatherText* is one of them.

but when you call *getActivity().findViewById()* or *findViewById()* you want to find the *weatherText* inside xml file of activity and there is no *weatherText* there so it will retun *null*

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `rootView` you are calling it directly on the `activity` so those two suggestions are equal (and activity is indeed the `context`).

But the activity doesn't know about the layout yet, you just inflated it from xml but it has not been given to the activity yet, and therefore can't be found. You do that by returning it from the `onCreateView` call you are in in your example code.